# json output is not as what expected

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, arrays

I have the following code which generates a good json output but it has '[' and ']' at the start and end respectively. You can also check the output at

http://android.ezinfotec.com/functions.php?method=getquestions

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from questions");
$i = 0;
        while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {

$output[] = array (
            "row".$i => array   (
                "id" => $fetch['id'],
                "answers" => $fetch['answers'],
                "status" => $fetch['ans_status'],
                "postedon" => substr($fetch['month'],0,3).' '.$fetch['day'].' '.$fetch['year'],
                "question" => $fetch['question'],
                "category" => $fetch['category'],
                "parent" => $fetch['parentcategory'],
                "authorid" => $fetch['author'],
                "authorname" => $fetch['author_name']   
                                )                   
                );
            $i++;           
        }
echo json_encode($output);
```

Here is my html page which generate [Object object] when I try to get the data from the url

```
$(function() {
$('#getdata').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/android/functions.php',
        type : 'GET',
        data : 'method=getquestions',           
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(s) {
            alert(s);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown)
        {
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest+' '+textStatus+' '+errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

});

I think it is because of the '[' and ']' I'm not able to access data using ajax. IN the success function i get [Object object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i got it you have to change your javascript to this code as below and let your php code to be run as it is you have written

```
success : function(s) {
                        for(var i =0 ;i < s.length; i++){
                              alert(s[i]["row"+i].id);
                              alert(s[i]["row"+i].answers);
                              alert(s[i]["row"+i].status);
                              alert(s[i]["row"+i].postedon);
                              alert(s[i]["row"+i].question);
                              alert(s[i]["row"+i].category);
                              alert(s[i]["row"+i].parent);
                              alert(s[i]["row"+i].authorid);
                              alert(s[i]["row"+i].authorname);
                       } 
                     }
```

Comment: since $Output is not a variable only the last record is shown. Still the '[' and ']' persist

Comment: Please check it i have change my answer as above

Comment: now it goes into the error function

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: ok add i as index to row as above and try it such as alert(s[i].row[i].id);

Comment: This works,
              alert([s[i].row0.id]);
             
         

But how do I navigate? if I set
    
alert([s[i].row+i.id]); i get NaN error

Comment: no just add index to row as above and try it such as alert(s[i].row[i].id); As you are providing index i to row in your php code. Please see i have edit the answer as above.

Comment: I tried your updated answer it shows

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: i got it working this is the code which works alert(t[i]["row"+i].id);. Sorry for the late reply but i was testing the code and its working

Comment: dats great could you please provide me the entire sript? I'm getting into a loop.

Comment: Noise's answer gave a nice json output please check the URL i gave in the post

Comment: I have edit my answer with your requirement for all data in the loop please check it out as above

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the help @THE ONLY ONE Good Job.

Comment: No Problem any time @Ashik Basheer

Comment: I've got a challenge for you @THE ONLY ONE, its json and javascript again

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754417/get-data-count-from-json-and-print-number-of-times

Answer (score 1):

Your output is currently of the form:

```
[
    {
        row0:
        {
            id: "17",
            answers: "0",
            status: "0",
            postedon: "Dec 4 2013",
            question: "How many courses within Aqeedah?",
            category: "91",
            parent: "89",
            authorid: "14",
            authorname: "Mehrakbar"
        }
    },
    {
        row1:
        {
            id: "18",
            answers: "0",
            status: "0",
            postedon: "Dec 10 2013",
            question: "what is jinn?",
            category: "97",
            parent: "89",
            authorid: "53",
            authorname: "Jack"
        }
    },
    etc
]
```

If the beginning and ending [ ] brackets were switched to { } braces, then your output will no longer be valid JSON. What do you want the output to look like?

If it's

```
{
    row0:
    {
        blah: blah
        blee: blah
    },
    row1:
    {
        blah: blah
        blee: blah
    }
}
```

that you are looking for, then change the

```
$output[] = array (
        "row".$i => array   (
```

to a

```
$output['row'.$i] = array (
```

and clean up the the corresponding parantheses.

Comment: Cool, now '[' and ']' are removed. But i'm not able to access the data via s.row0.id

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from questions");
$i = 0;
$output = array(); // add this line
```

Comment: do you get any data of variable s in `success : function(s)`?